# Landrush won`t start after vagrant reload

Tags: dns, vagrant, local, development-environment

At the begin I would like to highlight that I am new in vagrant.
I am using Vagrant 1.8.6, ubuntu/trusty64 box and landrush plugin.
I have a huge problem when I reload my vagrant then landrush won't start.
I tried to restart this plugin but I got this message: "Pid 5731 is not running. Has daemon crashed?" The landrush status says that the deamon status is unknown and .vagrant.d/data/landrush/run/landrush.pid exists, but process is not running. 
Here is the content of landrush log file:

`I, [2016-11-24T12:23:32.193495 #5458]  INFO -- : Starting RubyDNS server (v0.8.5)...
I, [2016-11-24T12:23:32.193953 #5458]  INFO -- : Listening on udp:0.0.0.0:10053
I, [2016-11-24T12:23:32.194205 #5458]  INFO -- : Listening on tcp:0.0.0.0:10053
I, [2016-11-24T12:34:54.220574 #5458]  INFO -- : Resource class: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A
I, [2016-11-24T12:34:54.221674 #5458]  INFO -- : Resource: #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A:0x00000101335f20 @address=#<Resolv::IPv4 10.10.12.10>>`

After vagrant landrush vms I got: No dependent VMs.

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true
 synced_folder_type = ENV.fetch('SYNC_TYPE', 'nfs')
 synced_folder_type = nil if 'vboxsf' == synced_folder_type
 config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/home/vagrant/www.mysite.pl',
         :type => synced_folder_type,
        :rsync__args => ['--verbose', '--archive', '--  delete', '-z']

 config.vm.define 'default', primary: true do |config|
   config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
   config.vm.hostname = 'shop.local.mysite.pl'
   if Vagrant.has_plugin? 'landrush'
    config.landrush.enabled = true
    config.landrush.tld = 'local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'mysite.pl.local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'www.mysite.pl.local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'test.mysite.pl.local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'mysite.com.local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'www.mysite.com.local.mysite.pl'
    config.landrush.host 'test.mysite.com.local.mysite.pl'
  end
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 22220, id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '10.10.12.10'
  config.vm.network :public_network, :bridge => 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'provision/scripts/install.sh'
 end
end
```

I can not find right way to resolve this problem. Only vagrant destroy helps but this is not the solution. I googled about it a few hours but nothing works. Anyone had a simmilar problem ? Thank you in advance for yours answers.

Comment: does it work better with `vagrant halt & vagrant up` ?

Comment: thanks for answer @FrédéricHenri. nope, this solution not working